# Problem in Edit from in Admin module.?

Tags: magento-1.9

While click on edit , its display blank page. how to solve this issue.

**code:**
controller code->

```
class Jorhna_Affiliates_Adminhtml_Jorhna_WithdrawlsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function editAction() 
    {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model  = Mage::getModel('affiliates/withdrawl')->getCollection();
        $model->getSelect()->join(array('affiliates' => Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'jorhna_affiliate'),
            'main_table.affiliate_id = affiliates.affiliate_id',
            array('affiliates' => '*','wstatus' => 'main_table.status','paypal' => 'main_table.paypal_email'));
        $model->addFieldToFilter('withdrawl_id',$id);


        foreach($model as $item) {
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($item->getData()); die;
            $modelID = $item->getWithdrawlId();

            //echo $modelID; die;
        }   
        if($modelID || $id == 0) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);

            $modelData = $model->getData();
            $modelData = $modelData[0];

            Mage::register('withdrawl_data', $modelData);
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('affiliates/items');
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Withdrawl Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Withdrawl Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Withdrawl News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Withdrawl News'));
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliates/adminhtml_withdrawls_edit'))
                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliates/adminhtml_withdrawls_edit_tabs'));
            $this->renderLayout();

        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Withdrawl does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

**edit.php**

```
class Jorhna_Affiliates_Block_Adminhtml_Withdrawls_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //echo "sfsrf"; die;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';


        $this->_blockGroup = 'affiliates';


        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_withdrawls';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Save Withdrawl'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Delete Withdrawl'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('affiliates_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'affiliates_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'affiliates_content');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('withdrawl_data')   ) {
            return Mage::helper('affiliates')->__("Edit Affiliate Withdrawl");
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Add Affiliate Withdrawl');
        }
    }
}
```

**Tabs.php**

```
class Jorhna_Affiliates_Block_Adminhtml_Withdrawls_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('withdrawls_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Withdrawl Information'));

  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {

    $this->addTab('form_section', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Withdrawl Detail'),
      'title'     => Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Withdrawl Detail'),
      'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliates/adminhtml_withdrawls_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
    ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

**Form.php**

```
class Jorhna_Affiliates_Block_Adminhtml_Withdrawls_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $this->setTemplate('affiliates/withdrawls/edit/tab/myform/form2.phtml');
    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAffiliatesData()) {
      $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAffiliatesData());
      Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAffiliatesData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('withdrawl_data')) {
      $form->setValues(Mage::registry('withdrawl_data'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

**form2.phtml**

```
<?php

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAffiliatesData()) {
      $UpdateData = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAffiliatesData();
      Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAffiliatesData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('withdrawl_data')) {
      $UpdateData = Mage::registry('withdrawl_data');
    }

    $myAffiliateCus = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                      ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                      ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$UpdateData['affiliate_id'])
                      ->addNameToSelect()
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('email')->getData();

    foreach ($myAffiliateCus as $item) {
      $AffiliateId     =   $item['entity_id'];
      $AffiliateName   =   $item['name'];
      $AffiliateEmail  =   $item['email'];
      $AffiliateCountry=   $item['billing_country_id'];
    }


    $AffiliatePaypalEmail   = $UpdateData['paypal'];
    $AccountBalance         = $UpdateData['total_amount'];
    $ReuestedAmount         = $UpdateData['amount_requested'];
    $Status                 = $UpdateData['wstatus'];
    $AdminNotice            = $UpdateData['admin_notice'];
    $WithdrawlId            = $UpdateData['withdrawl_id'];
    $ReqDateTime            = $UpdateData['req_made'];
    $Tax                    = $UpdateData['tax'];
    $Approval               = $UpdateData['approval'];
    $currencyCode           = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $currencySymbol         = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();

    if(Mage::helper('affiliates')->getWithdrawlFeeAmount()) {
      $fee = Mage::helper('affiliates')->getWithdrawlFeeAmount();
    }

    $AmountToPaid = $ReuestedAmount - $fee;
    $Dropdown     = false;
    $SelectedOne  = false;
    $SelectedFour = false;


    if(!isset($Tax)) {
      $Tax = 0.00;
    }

    if($Status == 'Pending' || $Status == 'pending') {
      $StatusText = Mage::helper('affiliates')->__($Status);
      $disabled     = "";
      $Dropdown = false;
      $SelectedOne = true; 
    } elseif($Status == 'Completed' || $Status == 'completed') {
      $StatusText = Mage::helper('affiliates')->__($Status);
      $Dropdown = false;
      $disabled     = "disabled='disabled'";
    } elseif($Status == 'Canceled' || $Status == 'canceled') {
      $StatusText = Mage::helper('affiliates')->__($Status);
      $Dropdown = false;
      $disabled     = "disabled='disabled'";
    } elseif($Status == 'Failed' || $Status == 'failed') {
      $StatusText = Mage::helper('affiliates')->__($Status);
      $Dropdown = true;
      $SelectedFour = true;
      $disabled     = "";
    }
?>
<div class="entry-edit">
   <div class="entry-edit-head">
      <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Withdrawal information'); ?></h4>
      <div class="form-buttons"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="fieldset " id="payment_data">
      <div class="hor-scroll">
         <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="hidden"><input id="withdrawl_id" name="withdrawl_id" value="<?php echo $AffiliateId; ?>" type="hidden"/></td>
              </tr>      
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="hidden"><input id="affiliate_id" name="affiliate_id" value="<?php echo $AffiliateId; ?>" type="hidden"/></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="affiliate_name"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Affiliate Name'); ?></label></td>
                  <td class="value">
                      <span id="affiliate_name"><strong><?php echo $AffiliateName; ?></strong></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="affiliate_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Affiliate Email'); ?></label></td>
                  <td class="value">
                    <span id="affiliate_email"><strong><?php echo $AffiliateEmail; ?></strong></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td class="label"><label for="paypal"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Affiliate Paypal Email'); ?></label></td>
                   <td class="value">
                      <span id="paypal"><strong style="color:red;";><?php echo $AffiliatePaypalEmail; ?></strong></span>
                    </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="total_amount"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Account Balance'); ?></label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                          <span id="total_amount"><strong><?php echo $currencySymbol.$AccountBalance; ?></strong></span>
                    </td>
               </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="amount_requested"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Requested Amount'); ?></label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                          <span id="amount_requested"><strong style="color: red;"><?php echo $currencySymbol.$ReuestedAmount; ?></strong></span>
                    </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                      <td class="label"><label for="fee"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Fee'); ?></label></td>
                      <td class="value">
                         <input <?php echo $disabled ?> onchange="subNumbers()" style="width:322px;" id="fee" name="fee" value="<?php echo $fee; ?>" type="text" class=" input-text"/>
                         <p id="fee_amount" class="note">
                          <span><?php echo $feeInformation; ?></span>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                 </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td class="label"><label for="tax"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Tax '); ?></label></td>
                   <td class="value">
                       <input <?php echo $disabled ?> onchange="subNumbers()" style="width:322px;" id="tax" name="tax" value="<?php echo $Tax; ?>" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="amount"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Amount (Excl. Tax)'); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                  <td class="value">
                      <input <?php echo $disabled ?> onchange="subNumbers()" style="width:322px;" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo $AmountToPaid; ?>" class="required-entry input-text required-entry" type="text"/>
                      <p class="note" id="note_amount"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Including fee ('.$currencyCode.')'); ?></span></p>
                   </td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                      <td class="label"><label for="admin_notice"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Admin Notice'); ?></label></td>
                      <td class="value">
                         <textarea <?php echo $disabled ?> style="width:316px; height:150px;" id="admin_notice" name="admin_notice" class=" input-text" ><?php echo $AdminNotice; ?></textarea> 
                      </td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                      <td class="label"><label for="w_status"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Transaction Status'); ?></label></td>
                      <td class="value">
                           <?php if($Dropdown):  ?>
                                 <select <?php echo $disabled ?> readonly="readonly" style="width:322px;" id="status" class=" select" name="status">
                                        <option <?php if($SelectedOne){ echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="Pending"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Pending'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="Completed"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Completed'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="Canceled"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Canceled'); ?></option>
                                        <option  <?php if($SelectedFour){ echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="Failed"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Failed'); ?></option>
                                  </select>       
                           <?php else : ?>
                                <span id="status"><strong><?php echo $StatusText; ?></strong></span>
                           <? endif; ?>
                      </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="request_time"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Request Date'); ?></label></td>
                  <td class="value">
                      <span id="request_time"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($ReqDateTime, 'medium', false); ?></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="approval"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Approval'); ?></label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                       <select <?php echo $disabled ?> style="width:322px;" id="status" class="select" name="approval">
                          <option value="not"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Approval Pending, Update Record'); ?></option>
                          <option value="approve"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Approve & Pay'); ?></option>

                          <?php if($Approval == 'approve' || $StatusText == 'Completed') { ?>
                            <option selected='selected' value="approve"><?php echo Mage::helper('affiliates')->__('Approved & Paid'); ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>       
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script language="javascript">
            function subNumbers() {

              alert('1');
              var fee       = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
              var tax       = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value);
              var old       = parseFloat(<?php echo $ReuestedAmount; ?>);
              var amount    = document.getElementById("amount");
              amount.value  = old - (tax + fee);
            }
        </script>

    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any error message or in log file?? Enable error display from index.php

Comment: No,  there is no error msg , but i think may be something wrong in form2.phtml ,